# Does Python Check ALL conditions in an multi-condition if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

I am curious if Python will continue checking conditions in an if statement if the first condition returns False. I'm wondering about this because I want to know if best practice is try to check conditions with low time-complexity before more complex checks.

Is there any difference between these two snippets?

```
if condition_1() and condition_2():
    do_something()
```

and

```
if condition_1():
    if condition_2():
        do_something()
```

Comment: There is no difference.  Python will lazily evaluate the boolean conditions left to right in an `if` statement.  If `condition_1()` is `False`, it will not try to evaluate `condition_2()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, python boolean operators do [short-circuit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Both code samples are semantically equivalent, but the first is more readable, as it has lower level of nesting.

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean it's preferable to write     "if simple_condition() and complex_condition():"      than the other way around?

Comment: @Joseph I think so.